# redux toolkit createAsyncThunk typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, async-await, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to call an API endpoint using @reduxjs/toolkit and typescript.

I've followed the example here, without success https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

I'm stuck on some typescript errors, what am I doing wrong?

**1°error**: when I do the dispatch like that in MessageController.tsx ,  typescript says:
*Argument of type 'AsyncThunk<any, void, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunk<any, void, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
index.d.ts(19, 3): 'type' is declared here.*

**2° error**: in message.slice.ts everytime I do a message.fulfilled or rejected or pending I get this:
*Property 'fulfilled' does not exist on type '(data: any) => AsyncThunk<any, void, {}>'.ts(2339)*

**message.slice.ts**

```
export const sendMessage = ( data) =>createAsyncThunk(
    `message/sendMessage`,
    async (data, thunkAPI) => {
        const response = await axios.post
        ( `/api/v1/xxx/test-messages`,
        data,
        httpOptions(getDefaultHeaders()));

       return response.data;
      }
    )
    
    
    
    const messageSlice = createSlice({
    name: "message",
    initialState: {
       message: {},
       loading: "idle",
       error: "",
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
       builder.addCase(sendMessage.pending, (state) => {
         state.message = {};
           state.loading = "loading";
       });
       builder.addCase(
        sendMessage.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
             state.message = payload;
             state.loading = "loaded";
       });
       builder.addCase(
        sendMessage.rejected,(state, action) => {
             state.loading = "error";
             state.error = action.error.message;
       });
    }
  })
  
  interface stateI{
  message: messageI;
}
interface messageI{
  loading: string;
}

  export const selectMessage = createSelector(
    (state: stateI) => ({
       message: state.message,
       loading: state.message.loading,
    }), (state) =>  state
  );
```

**MessageController.tsx**

```
  import {useAppDispatch} from '../../state/store';

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const { message } = useSelector(selectMessage);
    React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log(message)
     // TODO display the result of the api call in the page..
  }, [message]); 
  
  const handleClick =()=>{
    const data = {
      "environment": dropboxValue,
      "payload": textareaValue
    };

    dispatch(sendMessage(data))
    .then(() => {
      // TODO display the result of the api call in the page..
    })

  }
  
   //additional ui code for a button which when clicked trigger the api call (sendMessage)
```

**store.ts**

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
//other code not relevant (I think)
```

Answer (score 4):

Case 1: You create`useAppDispatch` wrong. Update can like this:

```
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

Case 2: You create thunk action wrong. You can update like this:

```
export const sendMessage = createAsyncThunk(
    `message/sendMessage`,
    async (data, thunkAPI) => {
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, I dont have the second error anymore but the first error on the dispatch call changed in 2 others error :
1) This expression is not callable.
  Type 'AnyAction' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
2)Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

Comment: the 2) actually make sense to me..I need to pass data to sendMessage() but you suggest to write the signature without the data argument

Comment: You are right about #2 but wrong about #1.  They had it correct.  They are creating a new hook so it needs to be a function.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question. Thanks